# Edit current visual studio document/file without write/save

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I am working on a visual studio extension where I have to edit the current code open in the code pane.
Here is how my file edit code goes:

```
DTE dTE = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(DTE)) as DTE;
TextDocument activeDoc = dTE.ActiveDocument.Object() as TextDocument;
string text =
activeDoc.CreateEditPoint(activeDoc.StartPoint).GetText(activeDoc.EndPoint);
string editted = Manipulate(text);            
//File.WriteAllText("File Address", editted); // I don't want to use this
```

I want to edit the current opened document such that the user will be able to use `ctrl+z` to revert any changes the extension makes.

Answer (score 2):

**CreateEditPoint** returns [EnvDTE.EditPoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.editpoint?view=visualstudiosdk-2017). You can use, for example, [EditPoint.Insert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.editpoint.insert?view=visualstudiosdk-2017#EnvDTE_EditPoint_Insert_System_String_) or [EditPoint.ReplaceText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.editpoint.replacetext?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) methods to change the document.